# javascript calling a class method

Tags: javascript

Hey I hava a function which acts like a class.

```
var myClass= function () {
        this.property = '';
        this.say() = function () {
            alert('Say Hello');
        }
```

When I initialize it like this

```
var myClassObj= new myClass();    
myClassObj.property = 'property';
myClassObj.say();
```

It gives me the error on initialization 
"Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function". Whats I am doing wrong.

Comment: `this.say() = function` => `this.say = function`. You don't want to invoke `this.say` immediately (which is `undefined` at this point).

Comment: `this.say()` tries to call `this.say`, but `this.say` does not exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `this.say` instead of `this.say()`.

Answer (score 1):

As hinted by Andrew, use **`this.say`** instead of `this.say()`

In your code you also miss closing `}` ,

It should be like this,

```
var myClass= function () {
    this.property = '';
    this.say = function () {
        alert('Say Hello');
        }
  }


var myClassObj= new myClass();    
myClassObj.property = 'property';
myClassObj.say();
```